# I just get the last table record?

Tags: servlets

I am trying to get the values that inserted into the database dynamically but I just got the last record using servlet and jsp. This my ado implementation

```
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM  eductional_details where schoolname=?"; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            educatiodetails educat = null;

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) con
                .prepareStatement(sql);

                    ps.setString(1, schoolname );
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {

                    educat = new educatiodetails();

                    String DateFrom = rs.getString("datForm");
                    String DateTo = rs.getString("DatTo");
                    String DiscriptDetails = rs.getString("Descript");

                     educat.setSchoolname(schoolname);
                     educat.setDataform(DateFrom);
                     educat.setDatato(DateTo);
                     educat.setDiscription(DiscriptDetails);

                    }
```

And here my servlet side

```
  String[] schoolname = request.getParameterValues("shoolname");
         String[] dataform = request.getParameterValues("Dateform");
         String[] datato = request.getParameterValues("Datato");
         String[] discription = request.getParameterValues("Dscript");

         for ( int i = 0 ; i < schoolname.length;i++ ) {
            educatiodetails edu = new educatiodetails();
                     edu.setSchoolname(schoolname[i]);
                     edu.setDataform(dataform[i]);
                     edu.setDatato(datato[i]);
                     edu.setDiscription(discription[i]);

                     EducatiIMP education = new EducatiIMP();
                     education.addEducation(edu); 
                     HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

                         addEducation.getList();
                         EducatiIMP ado = new EducatiIMP();

                        educatiodetails educat =   ado.geteducatiodetails(schoolname[i].toString());
                        session.setAttribute("educat",educat);
```

and here my jsp viewer

```
<c:forEach items="${educat}" var="item" varStatus="state" >
              <p><c:out value="${item.schoolname}"/></p>
 </c:forEach>
```

I tried for each but I got only the last recorded form my database, the insert working fine just the select or retrieve the user information not work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe below code might help you :

**Servlet:**

```
         String[] schoolname = request.getParameterValues("shoolname");
         String[] dataform = request.getParameterValues("Dateform");
         String[] datato = request.getParameterValues("Datato");
         String[] discription = request.getParameterValues("Dscript");
   //creating arraylist of type educatiodetails
          ArrayList<educatiodetails> ab= new ArrayList();
         for ( int i = 0 ; i < schoolname.length;i++ ) {
            educatiodetails edu = new educatiodetails();
                     edu.setSchoolname(schoolname[i]);
                     edu.setDataform(dataform[i]);
                     edu.setDatato(datato[i]);
                     edu.setDiscription(discription[i]);
          //storing value in arraylist
                    ab.add(edu);
             //setting attribute in r1
                      request.setAttribute("r1", ab); 
             request.getRequestDispatcher("yourjsppage").forward(request, response);
```

**Jsp** :

```
  <!--Here we are printing result-->
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${r1}">
   <!--printing values-->
          <p> ${item.schoolname}</p>
     </c:forEach>
```